# Threads basics: Why is the same code producing different output in different classes?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java.util.scanner, volatile

The following code works fine, that is it prints `Hello!` until I press `enter`. When I press enter, it stops. This is fine, as expected.

*But when I copy the **same code** into another class named `OneDataCached` (so it's just the name of the class which is different right) it does not work as expected. It rather prints `Hello!`, and when I press `enter`, it misses one line and then again starts printing `hello!`*

**I am confused about why this is happening, any hints or pointers will be greatly appreciated.**

```
public class One {
    static volatile boolean bool=true; 

    void stopThread(){
        bool=false;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                while(bool){
                    System.out.println("Hello!");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("Press Return to stop ...");

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        new One().stopThread();

    }

}
```

[image]

**AFTER COPYING THE CODE TO OneDateCached CLASS:-**

[image]

---

EDIT:-

```
public class OneDataCached {
    static volatile boolean bool=true; 

    void stopThread(){
        OneDataCached.bool=false;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                while(OneDataCached.bool){
                    System.out.println("Hello!");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

        System.out.println("Press Return to stop ...");

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        new One().stopThread();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using `OneDataCached.bool` or `One.bool`?  `static` is fun this way

Comment: @MadProgrammer Just to check that, I changed `bool` in the `while` loop's condition as well as in the `stopThread()` to `OneDataCached.bool`; But this did not help. Although your point is very much legit when I consider it. I edited the question.

Comment: Check the two top answers, you're changing the state of the wrong `bool`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just tried that. Did not help

Comment: Do `new OneDataCached().stopThread()` to get the behavior you want. Right now, you are still checking for `OneDataCached.bool` but modifying `One.bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you are calling

```
new One().stopThread();
```

instead of

```
new OneDataCached().stopThread();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to change it when I copied.. This worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've copied the code verbatim, then both versions will be calling

```
new One().stopThread();
```

Which means that in `OneDataCached.bool` is never changed.  `static` is not your friend and will cause all sorts of problems if you are not wary of it...

One solution might be to create a specialised `Runnable` which is self contained...

```
public class Message implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean bool = true;

    void stopThread() {
        bool = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (bool) {
            System.out.println("Hello!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then only ever interact with the instance you want to stop/modify, for example...

```
public class TestMessage {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Message message = new Message();
        Thread t = new Thread(message);
        t.start();

        System.out.println("Press Return to stop ...");

        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        message.stopThread();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the solution. It clarified my concept.

Answer (score 1):

If

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            while(bool){
                System.out.println("Hello!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

is declared in `One`, the name `bool` is referring to the `static` field declared in `One`. If the same code is declared in a class `SomeOther`, then it is referring to the `static` field declared in `SomeOther`.

However, `new One().stopThread();` will always modify the field declared in `One`, which your threads aren't looking at.